# How to get AngularJS Intellisense in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: angularjs

I am using VS2015 Enterprise. In which I have created MVC Project and added file named "angular.min.js" downloaded from [angularjs.org](https://angularjs.org/) but Angular intellisense is not working. Although I have referenced this file in my custom javascript file named "AngularScript.js" as shown in figure.

[image: reference added but still no intellisense]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The most easiest way to get intellisense** is to install angularjs package from "Manage Nuget Packages" as shown in figure below.

[image]

just install this package and this will resolve all your issues regarding intellisense and other. Do this and enjoy the AngularJS intellisense in your application. :-)